# python with pandas: select column with multi header

Tags: python, pandas

I read an xlsx file with two headers into a panda dataframe. Now I fail to select a row according to header 1 or two.

Googeling my probelm did not bring up an answer which worked, so I try it here

My Excel looks like this:

**Here you see an excerpt of the test excel:**

[image]
Now I read the excel file into pandas like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('XLsample.xlsx', sheet_name=0, header=[0,1], index_col=0)
```

How can I read a column dependent on header 0 or 1 ? I mean something like this:

```
persons = df[header[1]]['Name']

numbers = df[header[0]]['int']
```

thx for your support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
persons = df.xs('Name', axis=1, level=1)

numbers = df.xs('int', axis=1, level=0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is what I was looking for!